# Use React-Router in Service File to redirect on condition

Tags: reactjs, service, react-router

I have a service.ts file which hosts the functions for the api calls made in the application as well as interceptors to edit requests and responses. 
I want to be able to intercept any response coming to my application if it contains a 401 error and redirect the user to the login page.

The simplest solution was to use "window.location.href" to redirect as shown below:

```
    this.client.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
      if(error.response.status === 401 && store && store.getState().user){
        store.dispatch(actions.resetUser())
        window.location.href = '/login?authErr'
      }
      Promise.reject(error.response)
    })
```

however, as my application is wrapped with react-router I've heard it's bad to use the combo of the two.

How can I redirect in the service file which doesn't have a state or props? Every solution for router I find seems to use one or the other.

Comment: where are you calling this function from?

Comment: within the constructor of my service class

Comment: Does have to do with any of the components you hav ein your app? like, where exactly do you tell the App to run this service for you?

Comment: it's just a service file with a bunch functions that make api calls. Other components when they need access to server use the functions provided in this file. The app contacts this service from any component that needs to make a call to the api